# JQuery compare value of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have the following hidden input:

```
<input id="PostId" type="hidden" value="1" name="PostId" >
```

I want to check the value using jquery so that I can redirect to another page but I'm getting error:

```
 TypeError: "#PostId".val is not a function
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
 if (("#PostId").val() == 7 || ("#PostId").val() == 8) {

    window.location = baseUrl + "Post/Details/" + ("#PostId").val();
 }
```

Whats the correct syntax?

Comment: Jquery selector start with `$` or `jquery`. Use `$("#PostId").val()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is missing the `$`

```
if ($("#PostId").val() == 7 || $("#PostId").val() == 8) {
   window.location = baseUrl + "Post/Details/" + $("#PostId").val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) 
    {
      if ($("#PostId").val() == 7 || $("#PostId").val() == 8) {
         window.location = baseUrl + "Post/Details/" + $("#PostId").val();
         }
}(jQuery));
```